# Defining and referencing a generic type bound in Play template signature

Tags: java, scala, templates, generics, playframework-2.2

I have a number of sorted maps, keyed by a time and with a value of *some type*.  For illustration, consider that I have 3 maps (in Java):

```
SortedMap<OffsetDateTime, Foo> foo;
SortedMap<OffsetDateTime, Boo> bar;
SortedMap<OffsetDateTime, Baz> baz;
```

I wish to write a generic Play template that accepts a map, and a renderer function, and outputs each pair.

*Within* a template, I can define a *local* function with the following signature:

```
@renderTrace[T <: Any](trace: ImmutableSortedMap[OffsetDateTime, Option[T]], renderer: (T) => Html) = {
```

However, I would like to use this function in multiple templates, so I do not want to define it locally.  Rather, I had hoped to define it as its own template (in `RenderTrace.scala.html`).

Unfortunately, I don't seem be able able to specify the type construction `[T <: Any]` in the template signature.

How can I define a re-usable, generically typed function?

Comment: define it in an outside module and do `@import <yourmodule>`in the template?

Comment: Sorry @Ashalynd I don't follow your suggestion. To clarify my end: Since the signature of a template is not a regular Scala method signature (unlike the local functions, which pretty much are), I haven't found a way to include `[T <: Any]`.

Comment: I faced quite the same problem here - trying to write some generic templates while using scala only for "helpers" and in templates themeselves. So what solution did you chose finally?

Comment: @sandman: I used the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To flesh out @Ashalynd's suggestion, the template compiler doesn't appear to be smart enough to handle type parameters. Sometimes you can use an underscore as the type parameter (only when you don't care what the type is), but this isn't one of those cases.

A Play (now called twirl) template is essentially just a function that produces result of type `play.twirl.api.Html` (or `play.api.templates.Html` for Play 2.2). The templates compiler needs to be worked around, so define a helper package containing your function:

```
package viewhelpers

import play.twirl.api.Html // play.api.templates.Html for 2.2

object ViewExtension {

    def renderTrace[T <: Any](trace: ImmutableSortedMap[OffsetDateTime, Option[T]], renderer: (T) => Html): Html = ...

}
```

The implementation of `renderTrace` might not look as nice as it would in the view template, but at least it can work now.

Then in a view:

```
@(someParams: ....)
@import viewhelpers.ViewExtension

@{ViewExtension.renderTrace(...)}
```

Comment: Right. It's as I feared. Unfortunately for me, my controllers are in Java, so my helper may be even more unsightly. Or can I write Scala objects as well even in a Java-based Play app? (I shall investigate - but do you know?)

Comment: You can mix in Scala objects, as both Scala/Java versions are compiled by sbt anyway through play/activator.