# Type parameters in play templates

Tags: scala, playframework, type-parameter

Is it possible to send a type parameter to a view template? I'd like to do something like:

```
@formErrors(productForm)
```

where the view formErrors might have been defined as `[A](form:Form[A])`... but I can't seem to get this right. The template engine does not seem to allow that type of definition. (Related Java question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24359359/defining-and-referencing-a-generic-type-bound-in-play-template-signature).)

Comment: That's not a whole lot of info to work from, but I'd suggest that if you're thinking about type parameters in a template, you should maybe rethink your approach. My personal opinion is that a template should take pretty much just render-ready data and control parameters (typically booleans).

Comment: Tks for the response. What I'm after is a reusable piece of code that works in this case on a Form. I.e. instead of repeating the `if (productForm.hasErrors)` type of code in every template I could abstract it out into a separate view and pass productForm as a parameter...

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the linked Java question, it seems that an underscore can be sent, but under which circumstances, I haven't discovered yet. However in my case I can write:

```
@formErrors(form:Form[_])
@if( form.hasErrors ) { ... }
```

which was my intention, to be able to reuse the form error formatting/code. If anyone can shed any further light on the use of type parameters in templates, or the intention to support them in the future, that would be interesting.